# Is there an Invisible reCaptcha for iOS Application? (don’t require user clicks)

Tags: ios, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

Google offers a great way to protects your native Android app from malicious traffic: [SafetyNet reCAPTCHA API](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha)

With that you can implement an invisible captcha which 0 extra clicks. Check the following short video demo implementation: https://www.androidhive.info/2018/04/android-recaptcha-safetynet

Unfortunately, the SafetyNet reCAPTCHA API is Android only. I could not find any similar approach for native iOS. I only could find the following: https://github.com/fjcaetano/ReCaptcha
This is a nice approach, but lacks of the 0-clicks feature. I don't want my users to to select some raods or car pictures.

So do you know any possibility for iOS to implement invisible reCaptcha at 0-clicks?

Thanks for your support!

Comment: https://github.com/fjcaetano/ReCaptcha does implement 0 click, when your user takes action, you can call it behind in the background. If 0click feature fails it will pop up additional verification steps

Comment: Thanks Orkhan, you are right :)

Comment: @nanz the android hive link is not working. Do you have any other similar links?